# Why do I keep getting "Invalid Syntax" error with this code in this window? But when I run the same code in VS Code It works

Tags: python

This code is supposed to take a two digit number.

Then add the first digit to the second one.

```
two_digit_number = (input("Type a two digit number: ")

digit_0 = (int(two_digit_number[0]))

digit_1 = (int(two_digit_number[1]))

print(digit_0 + digit_1)
```

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis on the `two_digit_number = ` part of the code

Comment: Right.  This code would not work in VSC either.  You don't need the first paren in the `input` statement, and you don't need the outer parens in either of the `int(...)` calls.

Answer (score 1):

```
two_digit_number = input("Type a two digit number: ")

digit_0 = int(two_digit_number[0])
digit_1 = int(two_digit_number[1])

print(digit_0 + digit_1)
```

You forgot parenthesis in your first line of code, better - avoid unnecessary ones as well.